# Parsing data with hpple then displaying in labels

Tags: parsing, label, hpple

So far I have this:

I am trying to parse date with hpple from a webpage and then display it in labels. I don't know how to go about this. I guess I have to make the Secret variable in the void GoToSecretsList somehow equal the values the other void is getting... does anyone have any suggestions?

```
- (void)GoToSecretsList
{
UIViewController *vc;

vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecretsListID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 120, 500, 40)];
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

NSString *Secret;
Secret = @"Get value from website";

[myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"#1: %@", Secret]];


[[vc view] addSubview:myLabel];

}

 -(void)LoadSecrets {
// 1
NSURL *SecretsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/removed.com/xlxlx"];
NSData *SecretsHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:SecretsUrl];

// 2
TFHpple *secretsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:SecretsHtmlData];

// 3
NSString *secretsXpathQueryString = @"/secret";
NSArray *secretsNodes = [secretsParser searchWithXPathQuery:secretsXpathQueryString];

// 4
NSMutableArray *newSecrets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (TFHppleElement *element in secretsNodes) {
    // 5
    VOI *secret = [[VOI alloc] init];
    [newSecrets addObject:secret];

    // 6
    secret.title = [[element firstChild] content];

    // 7
    secret.url = [element objectForKey:@"href"];
}

 }
```

Edit: Now I just have this:

```
 - (void)GoToSecretsList
 {
UIViewController *vc;

vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecretsListID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 120, 500, 40)];
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


NSURL *SecretsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://removed.com/dsdsds"];
NSData *SecretsHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:SecretsUrl];


TFHpple *secretsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:SecretsHtmlData];


NSString *secretsXpathQueryString = @"/secret";
NSArray *secretsNodes = [secretsParser searchWithXPathQuery:secretsXpathQueryString];


[myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"#1: %@", secretsNodes]];
[[vc view] addSubview:myLabel];

}
```

But what variable has the information..? or what I am doing wrong? Because secretNodes isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some real html to help know what text you're looking for?

e.g. the following will get all the `<h2></h2>` nodes:

```
NSString *secretsXpathQueryString = @"//h2";//note double slashes for tag name
```

whereas this will get those with a specific class:

```
NSString *secretsXpathQueryString = @"//h2[@class='secret']";//note single quotes
```

Once you have the correct query, take a look at `TFHppleElement.h`  to see which properties you might investigate, for example:
`element.firstChild.content`